# Getting data between specific elements with the same name python XML

Tags: python, xml, element

Im very new to python and came across something which i couldn't seem to find a solution to. This is the XML data below:

```
<root>
    <prototype name="one">
        <child>
            <attr_node name="attr01"/>
            <attr_node name="attr02"/>
            <attr_node name="attr03"/>
        </child>
    </prototype>
    <prototype name="two">
        <child>
            <attr_node name="attr01"/>
            <attr_node name="attr02"/>
        </child>
    </prototype>
</root>
```

So what I've been trying to do is to get the data within the 'child' tag only from the 'prototype' tag with name="one". However, I couldn't find out how to specifically get data from elements with the same name.

The desired output is:

```
name="attr01"
name="attr02"
name="attr03"
```

Help would very much be appreciated! Thank you

Comment: Can you use `beautifulsoup` module?

Answer (score 0):

Below

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xml = '''<root>
    <prototype name="one">
        <child>
            <attr_node name="attr01"/>
            <attr_node name="attr02"/>
            <attr_node name="attr03"/>
        </child>
    </prototype>
    <prototype name="two">
        <child>
            <attr_node name="attr01"/>
            <attr_node name="attr02"/>
        </child>
    </prototype>
</root>'''

root = ET.fromstring(xml)
attrs =  [a.attrib['name'] for a in root.find('.//prototype[@name="one"]').findall('./child/attr_node')]
print(attrs)
```

output

```
['attr01', 'attr02', 'attr03']
```